# A hydrodynamic theory for systems with rich microscopic detail?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability, stochastic-processes

I've been looking at various models of stochastically interacting particle systems. Let's take for example the totally asymmetric simple exclusion process on a 1D lattice with some initial conditions. One can write a coarse-grained description of the evolution of this system in terms of its particle density and current (which turn out to be related to particle density in a rather simple manner). The fact that all particles treat every other particle in the same way helps a lot in doing so. So I was wondering whether such a coarse-grained description can be given for models which have two different interacting species? 
The fact that all particles are identical is now lost and our equations must take this into account? What about when there are infinite species and each particle treats every other particle differently? Can a hydrodynamic description for such a system be provided?

Any help would be appreciated :) I'll be happy to read up stuff if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: How coarse-grained is acceptable? Navier-Stokes equations work for basically any mixture if you are okay with a continuum. The [Chapman-Enskog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Enskog_theory) equation is less coarse-grained and all of the complex modeling of mixtures is reduced to finding an expression for the collision integral (see the link for examples of non-ideal particle interactions).

Comment: @tpg2114 any level of coarse-graining works actually! It's just that, I don't see an easy way to write down the equations for the dynamics at the microscopic level and was hoping that some amount of coarse-graining will help. I will check out the suggested link and will look into it. Anything else that you'd suggest me to try?

Comment: Well, Navier-Stokes definitely works for multi-species gases. And that starts from the Boltzmann equation, goes through the Chapman-Enskog equation, and ends at Navier-Stokes. So somewhere in there might be the answer to your question, but I don't have the answer on how to move along that path of equations. Maybe somebody will come along that does.

Comment: What is "totally asymmetric simple exclusion process on a 1D lattice"?